# How can I access the AST that VSCode creates

Tags: visual-studio-code, sapui5, vscode-extensions

I write a VSCode Extension for UI5 JavaScript. The most missing Feature is to have IntelliSense for UI5. Using UI5 typings it will work but not in all.

This works:

```
var testvar1 = new sap.m.Button();
```

Now i can use IntelliSense in VSCode in the testvar1.

The Problem e.g.:

```
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
  ], 
  function (Controller) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("", {

    });
  });
```

In this case there is a Controller variable in the function, this variable is defined with the Namespace before. I search now for a possibility to assign this variable in my Extension with the Namespace. I know this can be done in the AST but i have now idear how to get access to the AST to set:

```
Controller = sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller
```

The goal is to have the full IntelliSense now in the variable Controller

I hope it is clear what i want, so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to give a type to `Controller`, try using [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/):

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (/** @type {sap.m.Controller} */Controller) {
  // ...
});
```

To answer the original question, you can access/modify the AST with a [TypeScript server plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin). This is not trivial so I would try to avoid doing this unless you really need to.

Comment: Great this is working. Is it also possible to assign the this keyword with this type. I searched in the jsdocs but it doesn't work. If you have any idea will be great.enter image description here

Comment: UI5 is slowly starting to support TypeScript: https://github.com/SAP/ui5-typescript